# How do I get the default cell separator color? Also, how do I set separator color per cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to add a cell in the bottom that shows only if the app is loading more results when the user scrolls to the bottom of a tableview. I already did that. The problem is that it's a cell. So when I scroll down even further, the separator shows that it's just another cell in the table. I want to hide that. I have to change that cell's separator color, how do I do that to a particular cell? Also, Where/when do i do that?

I realize that if I change that cell's color (let's say it's #5), when I get the results and load them in, won't that also result in cell #5 still having an invisible separator? So how do I set it back to the default color? More particularly how do I get the default color for a tableviewcellseparator programmatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple trick: you have to add en empty `UIView` inside your `UITableView` in Storyboard. The set the `height = 0`.

The last separator of the `UITableView` magically disappears.

[image]

---

**Edit**:

You will also need to edit your [`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath:) like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];

    if (indexPath.row == [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[self numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView]-1]-1) {
        //this is the last cell
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, cell.bounds.size.width, 0, 0);
    } else {
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.size.width, 0);
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That will help a lot. But it only removes the separator for all cells _below_ my "Loading..." cell. The loading cell's lower separator still shows.

Comment: Damn, still nothing. I did find a way to fix it though. I added another empty subview to the empty UIView, and set it's y-position to -1 and it's height to 2. That seems to fix the issue. I would have done this to the original UIView, but I can't change it's y-position.

Answer (score 0):

Separator colour is a property of the table view, you can get or set it like so:

```
self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

But I don't think you cannot change the separator colours of a individual cell.

If you truly need that level of customization, you should probably just draw the separator bar yourself as, for example, a thin `UIView` at the top of the cell. Then you can change its appearance to whatever you want.